# FreeBSD jails access

Tags: freebsd, jail

I want to run an application inside `jail` so that allowed users can only connect to the jailed environment (application) and nothing else on my box.

But they need to be able to connect to the jail over the network and I have only 1 public ip which is being used by my box.

How can I make the jail accessible to others?

Comment: Use the firewall to forward connections to a specific unused port to the jail. On the jail, set up sshd to listen on that port. That's it.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what service you want people to connect to in the jail, you can either use firewall rules to forward incoming public traffic on public ports to the appropriate port on the jail's private IP, or you can set up a proxy that will do the job for you -- and incidentally add some protection to your jail.

I do this regularly for jails that run web servers.  The jails are on private IP addresses, so they don't have access to the web.  The only way they can be reached is using an HTTP reverse proxy that runs on the jailserver.  You can use [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) or [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) as a reverse proxy, but I prefer "[pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound)" for its simplicity.  You can find it in the ports tree at [ports/www/pound/](http://www.freshports.org/www/pound).

Other services can use inbound proxies as well.  [nginx can be used as an IMAP proxy](http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapProxyExample).  This is handy if you want to be able to upgrade IMAP without taking it down.  Just proxy it to a second jail, upgrade the first jail, then cut over service to the upgraded jail while so you can upgrade the standby.  Since running a jail takes pretty much no extra resources than running something natively on the server, you get all the benefits of virtualization without the performance hit.

If you need people to connect to your box via SFTP, then you either need to use a non-standard port (perhaps with a firewall rule and/or NAT to forward the traffic), or you can set up the SFTP accounts so that they will chroot into the jail directories where they're supposed to be.  This doesn't run the SFTP server **in** the jail, but the result is the same.

If you need to provide shell access to the jail via SSH, then I suspect you have only two options.  First would be, as with SFTP, to use a non-standard port and a firewall rule.  The second, more complex option, would be to use a shell account on your jail server that has magic variables in the account's `.ssh/authorized_keys` file.  Have a look at [`man sshd`](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sshd#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT) under the "AUTHORIZED_KEYS FILE FORMAT" section.

In brief, you probably want to set up something like `command="command"` for the keys that will connect to you.  The down side is that for anyone who will connect, you will need to get their public key ahead of time.  And your clients will obviously need to have keys set up.  But the up side is that you can create shell accounts on your jail host that either `jexec` into the jail, or run another ssh that gets there.

Comment: I want to run vncserver instances and be able to provide selected users access to access that i.e. user1 on :1 , user2 on :2 and so on. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: You're aware that running a vnc server also means running an X stack, right?  Do you really want to run the X-windows system in a jail?  If so, I suggest you provide the SSH access on your jail server, then use SSH tunnels to get access to VNC.  VNC is not a secure protocol (its passwords are in cleartext), so forcing its traffic through an SSH tunnel will provide better security.

Comment: @ghoti, VNC can use TLS to secure the connection, but some clients don't support it and you have to configure it. Great writeup and advice though.

Comment: @ghoti Thanks for the detailed info. I am a newbie. How can I tunnel VNC inside ssh?

Comment: hari, VNC inside SSH is really easy, but depends on your client.  If you're using a command-line `vncviewer` command (I recommend `ssvncviewer` from [`ports/net/ssvnc`](http://www.freshports.org/net/ssvnc)) you can use the `-via` option, which is well documented on the man page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different port for access or an internal IP letting people use ssh/vpn tunnels.